# jasper reports: exporting table with grouped headers to excel

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

let's say, I have a table in my report with complex header like this

[image: column report example]

when I export it to either xls or xlsx using Jasper Reports Server it prints like this (Excel 2010):

[image: column report fail]

`Column 1` height should be equal to `Column 2` + `Header` height

Enviroment: Jasper Reports Server CE 4.5.1, tried latest version (5.0.4) - same (sad) result

How can I correctly export such header to Excel?

Does anybody knows any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JasperReportsServer is configured to collapse row spans, see the `collapseRowSpan` property of the xlsExportParameters bean in `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`.

Set that property to `false` to have the group headers span two rows.

iReport has the same property at `Options/Export Options/Excel/Collapse Row Span`.